# Split date complex format with Pandas dataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've the following Pandas dataFrame with a complex date string format i.e. "2020-11-15T17:00:00", read from a csv file.
I'd like to have a new frame with a comlumn in excel date format as following "11/15/2020" in order to sort after writing frame.to_excel(...).
Is it possible?

'''

```
    data                stato   codice_regione
0   2020-11-15T17:00:00 ITA     13
1   2020-11-15T17:00:00 ITA     17
2   2020-11-15T17:00:00 ITA     18
3   2020-11-15T17:00:00 ITA     15
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data to datetime and extract the date:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

or you can just extract the date part:

```
df['date'] = df['data'].str[:10]
```

which gives you `2020-11-15` and excel would be smart enough to recognize that as a date.